# Calculating most frequent level by category with plyr

Tags: r, plyr

I would like calculate the most frequent factor level by category with plyr using the code below.  The data frame `b` shows the requested result.  Why does `c$mlevels` only have the value "numeric"?

```
require(plyr)
set.seed(0)
a <- data.frame(cat=round(runif(100, 1, 3)),
                levels=factor(round(runif(100, 1, 10))))
mode <- function(x) names(table(x))[which.max(table(x))]
b <- data.frame(cat=1:3,
                mlevels=c(mode(a$levels[a$cat==1]),
                       mode(a$levels[a$cat==2]),
                       mode(a$levels[a$cat==3])))
c <- ddply(a, .(cat), summarise,
           mlevels=mode(levels))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `summarise`, `plyr` seems to "not see" the function declared in the global environment before checking for function in `base`:

We can check this using Hadley's handy `pryr` package. You can install it by these commands:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("pryr")


require(pryr)
require(plyr)
c <- ddply(a, .(cat), summarise, print(where("mode")))
# <environment: namespace:base>
# <environment: namespace:base>
# <environment: namespace:base>
```

Basically, it doesn't read/know/see **your** `mode` function. There are *two* alternatives. The first is what @AnandaMahto suggested and I'd do the same and would advice you to stick with it. The other alternative is to not use `summarise` and call it using `function(.)` so that the `mode` function in your global environment is "seen".

```
c <- ddply(a, .(cat), function(x) mode(x$levels))
#   cat V1
# 1   1  6
# 2   2  5
# 3   3  9
```

Why does this work?

```
c <- ddply(a, .(cat), function(x) print(where("mode")))
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

Because as you see above, it reads your function that sits in the `global environment`.

```
> mode # your function
# function(x)
#     names(table(x))[which.max(table(x))]
> environment(mode) # where it sits
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

as opposed to:

```
> base::mode # base's mode function
# function (x) 
# {
#     some lines of code to compute mode
# }
# <bytecode: 0x7fa2f2bff878>
# <environment: namespace:base>
```

[**Here's an awesome wiki**](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Environments) on `environments` from Hadley if you're interested in giving it a reading/exploring further.

Comment: +1, This is a *much* better answer than mine. I was too lazy to explore where plyr was looking for "mode" so I just renamed and simplified it.

Comment: Thank you for answer, it is working now.  I try to summarize:  Mode is already existing in the global environment and therefore plyr is using this one insted of the mode function provided by me.

Comment: @user2126360, `mode` exists in `base`.

Comment: nope. your function exists in global environment. but `summarise` "sees" a different `mode` which is by default in `base`. that's why @AnandaMahto explained in his edit that it is not wise to use all default names used already in R as there are more chances for your code to break.

Comment: See also the `here` function: `ddply(a, .(cat), here(summarise), mlevels=mode(levels))`.  The explanation in the docs should help.

Answer (score 2):

You have pretty much exclusively used existing function names in your example: `levels`, `cat`, and `mode`. Generally, that doesn't create much of a problem--for example, calling a data.frame "df" doesn't break R's `df()` function. But it almost always leads to more ambiguous or confusing code, and in *this* case, it made things "break". Arun's answer does a *great* job of showing why.

You can easily fix your problem by renaming your "mode" function. In the example below, I've simplified it a little bit in addition to renaming it, and it works as you expected.

```
Mode <- function(x) names(which.max(table(x)))
ddply(a, .(cat), summarise,
      mlevels=Mode(levels))
#   cat mlevels
# 1   1       6
# 2   2       5
# 3   3       9
```

Of course, there's a really cumbersome workaround: Use `get` and specify where to search for the function.

```
> mode <- function(x) names(table(x))[which.max(table(x))]
> ddply(a, .(cat), summarise, mlevels = get("mode", ".GlobalEnv")(levels))
  cat mlevels
1   1       6
2   2       5
3   3       9
```